# Invariant vs variant coordinates under axis orientation reversal

Tags: python, coordinates, orientation, axis, coordinate-systems

For algorithms involving the coordinates of an object in a Cartesian coordinate system (for instance the coordinates of a bounded interval in a one-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system), what are the advantages or drawbacks of expressing them in coordinates *independent* * from axis orientation (for instance `x_min`, and `x_max`), *versus* in coordinates *dependent* ** on axis orientation (for instance `x_left` and `x_right`, or alternatively, `x_left` and `width`)?

For instance, for an algorithm that tests if two bounded intervals overlap, would you write

```
def test_overlap(x_min_1, x_max_1, x_min_2, x_max_2):
    """Test if two bounded intervals overlap.
    Coordinates are independent from axis orientation.
    """
    assert x_min_1 <= x_max_1
    assert x_min_2 <= x_max_2
    return x_min_1 <= x_max_2 and x_min_2 <= x_max_1
```

or either

```
def test_overlap(x_left_1, x_right_1, x_left_2, x_right_2):
    """Test if two bounded intervals overlap.
    Coordinates are dependent on axis orientation.
    """
    assert (x_left_1 <= x_right_1 and x_left_2 <= x_right_2
            or x_left_1 >= x_right_1 and x_left_2 >= x_right_2)

    if x_left_1 <= x_right_1:  # x-axis oriented to the right
        return x_left_1 <= x_right_2 and x_left_2 <= x_right_1
    else:                      # x-axis oriented to the left
        return x_left_1 >= x_right_2 and x_left_2 >= x_right_1
```

or

```
# Here the orientation of the x-axis cannot be deduced from the arguments,
# so you need to pass it explicitly to the algorithm.
def test_overlap(x_left_1, width_1, x_left_2, width_2, x_orientation):
    """Test if two bounded intervals overlap.
    Coordinates are dependent on axis orientation.
    """
    assert width_1 >= 0
    assert width_2 >= 0
    assert x_orientation in ["right", "left"]

    if x_orientation == "right":  # x-axis oriented to the right
        x_right_1 = x_left_1 + width_1
        x_right_2 = x_left_2 + width_2
        return x_left_1 <= x_right_2 and x_left_2 <= x_right_1
    else:                         # x-axis oriented to the left
        x_right_1 = x_left_1 - width_1
        x_right_2 = x_left_2 - width_2
        return x_left_1 >= x_right_2 and x_left_2 >= x_right_1
```

---

<sup>* Coordinates specify a particular point and vary with the coordinate system. When I say "coordinates independent from axis orientation", it implies that the *point* under consideration vary to leave the coordinates unchanged under axis orientation reversal.</sup>

<sup>** When I say "coordinates dependent on axis orientation", it implies that the *coordinates* vary to leave the point under consideration unchanged under axis orientation reversal. This is the standard usage.</sup>

Comment: It's hard to think of coordinates without assuming something about their axes, hence your first option is not only less verbose but also easier to reason about.

Comment: "Better" in what sense?

Comment: @Will The first option is the one that does _not_ assume anything about the x-axis: it can either be left-oriented or right-oriented, the formula remains the same.

Comment: @martineau Good question. Which version of the above function would you use in practice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's "better", but the way I did it in one project—which worked out very well—was to define a `class` similar to the following:

```
class Interval(object):
    """ Representation of a closed interval.

    "a" & "b" can be any numeric type, or any other type than can be
    compared. If the type can also be incremented by 1, then it
    will be possible to iterate between the two values in
    ascending order.
    """
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.lowerbound, self.upperbound = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)

    def __contains__(self, val):
        return self.lowerbound <= val <= self.upperbound

    # Implemented as a generator (so no 'next' method is needed)
    def __iter__(self):
        nextvalue = self.lowerbound  # Initialize iteration state.
        while nextvalue <= self.upperbound:
            yield nextvalue
            nextvalue += 1
```

The `__contains__()` method controls how expressions like `if x in interval:` check the `x` value against the `Interval`'s upper- and lower-bounds. (In my own application, I used `Date`s as interval bounds.)

Doing it this way gives you control over how nearly everything works, plus you'll also be able add specialized methods to it if desired. For example: a `test_overlap()` method could do what your want in whatever way you decide to it. In fact, such a method could be written to return the result as a `Interval`.

Comment: Thank you for this nice container and iterable data structure. So you would use my first approach instead of my second one (`lowerbound` and `upperbound` instead of `leftbound` and `rightbound`). But why, what is the advantage?

Comment: I don't think there's anything "better" between them, it's just equivalent mathematical logic. Also what we're talking about here is what goes on internally _within_ the class. What you do there should depend on efficiency, readability, maintainability—plus you might also just like one way or the other for reasons like it's easier or less typing to write `<` instead of  `<=`. Personally I like the latter because I preferred using closed, rather than open-intervals in the application I designed them to be used in, so I did them that way.

Comment: Another thing to note about my implementation is there are no `assert` statement because it effectively sorts the two arguments and stores the one withe smaller value in `self.lowerbound` and the other in the other attribute—so there's no need to use assertions. You might want to put other kinds in if you wish, of course, but type-checking is generally considered not "pythonic".

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding. When I said you chose `lowerbound` and `upperbound` instead of `leftbound` and `rightbound`, I was not referring to closed vs open intervals. What I meant is that `leftbound` and `rightbound` refer to the left endpoint of the interval and the right endpoint of the interval respectively, while `lowerbound` and `upperbound` refer to the endpoint that has the minimal coordinate and the endpoint that has the maximal coordinate respectively.

Comment: You can name them whatever you want. You can also define what they mean to be the reverse of what's in my answer—you could even make it so an `Interval` could have either characteristic specified at creation time, as well as be opened or closed. A class makes all that possible in a relatively easy way.